# Update Hystrix configuraitons at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hystrix

I'm using Hystrix in a Spring Cloud application with commands defined like

```
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "GroupKey", commandKey = "dummy",
        threadPoolProperties = {
                @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "10")
        })
public Observable<String> dummy() {
    return new ObservableResult<String>() {
        @Override
        public String invoke() {
            return "OK";
        }
    };
}
```

I want to update the `coreSize` (size of thread pool) property at runtime. How can that be done? Is it possible? Or should I look for different solution?

I've been reading about Archaius and how it's used for updating configurations but I don't understand how it can be used for what I'm trying to accomplish.

In my main class I'm using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which adds `ArchaiusAutoConfiguration` to the application.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Create a config.properties file for Archaius, containing the line

```
hystrix.threadpool.YOUR_GROUP_KEY.coreSize=10
```

Make sure that the file is on your application's classpath or explicitly configure the location in a JVM property, e.g.

```
-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///opt/myapp/config.properties
```

Archaius usually reads the file once a minute, so settings will be applied without application restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you would to read the updated configuration at custom time interval than look at the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712393/netflix-archaius-dynamic-configuration/35712984?noredirect=1#comment59108101_35712984)